# Thesaurus for linguistic and NLP terms

Tags: terminology

Does there exist any reference thesaurus for linguistic and NLP  terms? I know that Wikipedia articles often contain synonyms, but I would like to have a mere thesaurus that I could go through easily (vs. a full encyclopedia) to make sure I know all the jargon (e.g. parts-of-speech = POS = word classes = morphological classes = lexical tags).

Comment: There's a very useful thesaurus of linguistic terminology (probly pretty lean on CL/NLP terms, since they change so fast) at the end of David Crystal's _Cambridge Encyclopedias_, of Language and of the English Language. That's a start. The etymology of traditional grammatical terms (not all, and practicly no CL/NLP) [is available here](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/wow/grammar.latin.html) for those terms (the majority) that stem from Latin sources.